# dynamic radio buttons radio group and views are not working

Tags: android, android-layout, jdbc, android-view

i want to create radio buttons dynamically from the database i already browse this issue but not working. when i call the function to get the values from the database and pass values for application context the function is called and there is no error in calling the function or returning the value but when the view return linear layout it shows blank xml as initially created. i need help to show those values it the view. thanks in advance.
here is the code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy=new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    dbcon=DBConnection.instance(this);
    dbcon.connect("ip:1433", "pas", "login", "db");
    Context cntxt=getApplicationContext();

    try {

        Thread.sleep(10);

        String city=getIntent().getExtras().getString("city");
        String choice=getIntent().getExtras().getString("choice");

        LinearLayout ll=new LinearLayout(cntxt);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        ImageView iv=new ImageView(cntxt);
        RadioGroup.LayoutParams prams=new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        prams.setMargins(0, 2, 0, 2);


        RadioGroup rg=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.RRG);

        ll=dbcon.GetResultList(rg,choice,city,iv,cntxt,ll);

        ((ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.RRG)).addView(ll);



    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

here is the function which i called from the activity:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public LinearLayout GetResultList(RadioGroup rg,String choice,String city,ImageView iv,Context context, LinearLayout ll) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(conn==null){

    }
    try{
        RadioButton rb;
        rg.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);

            Statement st=conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from AM_NATIONAL where ca_city="+city+ "order by cvg_count");

            while (rs.next()){
                rb=new RadioButton(context);
                rb.setId(rs.getInt(1));
                rb.setText(rs.getString(2)+"\n");
                rb.setText(rs.getString(3)+"\n");
                rb.setText(rs.getInt(8));

                byte[] photo=rs.getBytes(4);
                Bitmap bitmap;
                bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(photo, 0, photo.length);
                iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                rb.setEnabled(false);
                rg.addView(iv);
                rg.addView(rb);
                ll.addView(rg);

            }
            rs.close();
            st.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException e){

        }
    return ll;

}
```

and here is the xml file which i use for this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     tools:context=".ResultActivity" >

     <ScrollView
         android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

         <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:orientation="vertical" >

             <RadioGroup 
                 android:id="@id/RRG"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

             </RadioGroup>

         </LinearLayout>
     </ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: why are you adding imageview inside Radio group?

Comment: because i want to show the images from database with radio buttons

Comment: but issue is not there issue is that then linear layout returns it is blank

Comment: debug and check where is actual error you are getting

Comment: breakpoint at line number rb=new RadioButton(context);

Comment: it is showing this in logcat but not showing the results:

Comment: 09-01 13:50:05.070: D/dalvikvm(26709): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 417K, 4% free 16765K/17335K, paused 17ms, total 28ms
09-01 13:50:05.077: I/System.out(26709): [CDS]close[33613]
09-01 13:50:05.079: I/System.out(26709): close [socket][/0.0.0.0:33613]
09-01 13:50:05.080: I/System.out(26709): close [socket][/0.0.0.0:33613]
09-01 13:50:05.168: D/ActivityThread(26709): ACT-AM_ON_RESUME_CALLED ActivityRecord{420b64a8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@420b5c70 {com.example.ecpvotesystem/com.example.ecpvotesystem.ResultActivity}}

Comment: 09-01 13:50:05.177: D/ActivityThread(26709): ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / ActivityRecord{420b64a8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@420b5c70 {com.example.ecpvotesystem/com.example.ecpvotesystem.ResultActivity}}
09-01 13:50:05.329: V/InputMethodManager(26709): onWindowFocus: null softInputMode=272 first=true flags=#1810100
09-01 13:50:05.330: V/InputMethodManager(26709): Starting input: view=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@420b73e0
09-01 13:50:05.331: V/InputMethodManager(26709): Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@42063f60 ic=null

Comment: dont check log cat i said check in debug mode so you can test line by line value of variable is null or not

Comment: 09-01 13:50:05.332: V/InputMethodManager(26709): START INPUT: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@420b73e0 ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@42063f60 controlFlags=#104
09-01 13:50:05.347: V/InputMethodManager(26709): Starting input: Bind result=InputBindResult{com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy@42016220 com.android.inputmethod.latin/.LatinIME #2283}
09-01 13:50:05.400: D/OpenGLRenderer(26709): Flushing caches (mode 0)
09-01 13:50:05.646: I/System.out(26709): [CDS]close[40500]

Comment: dont post logcat in comment

Comment: 09-01 13:50:05.649: I/System.out(26709): close [socket][/0.0.0.0:40500]
09-01 13:50:05.650: D/dalvikvm(26709): create interp thread : stack size=32KB
09-01 13:50:05.651: D/dalvikvm(26709): create new thread
09-01 13:50:05.651: D/dalvikvm(26709): update thread list
09-01 13:50:05.651: D/dalvikvm(26709): threadid=14: interp stack at 0x52627000
09-01 13:50:05.651: D/dalvikvm(26709): threadid=14: created from interp
09-01 13:50:05.651: D/dalvikvm(26709): start new thread
09-01 13:50:05.651: D/dalvikvm(26709): threadid=14: notify debugger

Comment: in debugging i set break point but it is also not working

Comment: may be your rs is null

Comment: it is not waiting for this and show the layout

Comment: but i assign rs as you can see the calling GetResultList function

Comment: and the table contains values and is not null

Comment: Thanks for the help @RohanPawar rs was empty as there is mistake with intent calling city. thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breakpoint on line
    `ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery`
check that your rs is not null in debug mode if rs will null add default views to Layout so it will not return null layout